# What are some words that can translate "butterface" into Russian?

Tags: сленг, лексикон

According to the UrbanDictionary website, **butterface**/**butter face** is an American slang for:

> A girl who is hot, except for her (*but her*, *butter*) face.

Can you think of any common slang or playful words with that meaning in Russian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closest pun I can remember: `сзади - пионерка, спереди - пенсионерка`, "a teenager from behind, an old lady from the front". It's mostly used for misleadingly-dressed elder women, but might indicate hot body and not-so-hot face.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact same slang word in Russian for that, but you can try `крокодил`.

Comment: «Крокодил» is for a woman who is ugly all over, not only for her face.

Answer (score 2):

Can't propose exact form, which means hot body and ugly face at the same time, but ugly girl may be described as `страшная` (literally `scary`, figuratively `ugly`). But this doesn't describe body attractiveness. So, maybe you need to do this additionally, like `фигуристая, но страшная` (`has a slender figure/hot body but ugly`).

Comment: "Уродина" used very often to describe girl/woman with ugly face.

Comment: So, "уродина, но с фигурой" (фигуристая уродина)